# How to use IF Formula in excel correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use the IF formula in excel but am getting errors.

In Column E i have the business type which consists of New Business, Renewals, Upsells.

If the value is New Business or Upsell I need to have the value of 4500 entered, if it equals Renewal i need to have the value 300 entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
=IF(OR(E2="New Business",E2="Upsell"),4500,IF(E2="Renewal",300,""))
```

or

```
=IF(OR(E2="New Business",E2="Upsell"),4500,300)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Assuming your header information is in row 1 and data starts in row 2, if you place this formula in F2 (or whichever column you want your data to appear) and copy-down to the last row in your sheet, you should get the right answer for each value.

```
=if(or(E2="New Business", E2="Upsell"), 4500, 300)
```

Comment: i'm a pedant meself. it was no trouble.  re: OR, I lean the other way. It's more cumbersome, but future maintainers of the spreadsheet will have more idea of what's going on if everything's identified.  Worse (perhaps), i also want to change the last `,""` to catch everything else and return "Invalid Type"